# Dismiss PopupMenu with remote control android

Tags: android, contextmenu, dismiss, onkeydown, popupmenu

I'm programming on an Android Set-Top-Box, so I also have to implement onKey Events for the delivered remote control.

My Problem is, that I'm creating a new PopupMenu and then want to dismiss it by certain keyEvents. In fact it should always dismiss, when the user hit other keys than (Up/Down).
At the moment it only disapears when the Back Button or an item are pressed. When I'm touching outside the Popupmenu it also disapears. But I need to be able to dismiss the Menu when I'm hitting for example the Key KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2.

The main problem is, that I'm not able to catch ANY onKeyDown/Up etc. events at all!!
It simply don't catch any KeyEvent in my Activity when the Popupmenu is showing.

Is there any possibility in catching key events when in Popupmenu/ContextMenu mode?

EDIT: Here is an example how my onKeyDown catch in the MainActivity looks like:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.e("Key hit","true");
    try {
        switch (keyCode) {

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
            Log.e("Test"," catch left");
            return true;

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0:
            Log.e("Test","hit 0");
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2:
            Log.e("Test","hit 2");

            break;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("onKeyDown", "exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: post the code you are using to try to catch the key events.

Comment: see my edit. I really didn't do anything special, it seems just like it's very difficult to handle keyEvents when the PopupMenu is displayed.

Comment: Did you ever figure how to avoid that PopupMenu blocks all keyinputs ?